# Why LXC requires restart?

Tags: linux, permissions, lxc, cgroup, namespaces

LXC documentation says:

> Just before you create your first container, you probably should logout and login again,
>   or even reboot your machine to make sure that your user is placed in the right cgroups.

Can somebody explain why this is required to run something like:

```
lxc-usernsexec -m b:0:100000:1 -- bash
```

I have proper mappings in `/etc/subgid` and `/etc/subuid`. But this command simply says permission denied before I reboot. What does *right cgroups* stands for?

**EDIT**

Before installing LXC:

```
jml@somehost:~$ cat /proc/self/cgroup 
2:name=systemd:/user/1002.user/123.session
```

After installing LXC and rebooting:

```
jml@somehost:~$ cat /proc/self/cgroup 
11:hugetlb:/user/1002.user/5.session
10:perf_event:/user/1002.user/5.session
9:blkio:/user/1002.user/5.session
8:freezer:/user/1002.user/5.session
7:devices:/user/1002.user/5.session
6:memory:/user/1002.user/5.session
5:cpuacct:/user/1002.user/5.session
4:cpu:/user/1002.user/5.session
3:cpuset:/user/1002.user/5.session
2:name=systemd:/user/1002.user/5.session
```

Note that there is no difference in groups I'm belonging to. The only change I noticed are those `cgroups`. Now having those `cgroups` impacts the ability to map a user in the namespace?

Comment: If you run a daemon, it needs restart. See https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/is-it-necessary-to-reload-subuid-subgid/12676

Answer (score 1):

Group IDs (GIDs) are inhereted from the parent process. When you login you get a terminal, launched with a set of GIDs and each process you launch gets the same GIDs. For security reasons you can't change the GIDs yourself and any changes don't take effect until you log out and log in so the `login` process launches your terminal with the new GIDs.

Comment: Unfortunately this has nothing to do with groups my user belongs to. They are exactly the same.